# Can an OCR run in a split-second if it is highly targeted? (Small dictionary)

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am looking for an open source ocr (maybe tesseract) that uses a dictionary to match words against. For example, I know that this ocr will only be used to search for certain names. Imagine I have a master guest list (written) and I want to scan this list in under a second with the ocr and check this against a database of names.

I understand that a traditional ocr can attempt to read every letter and then I could just cross reference the results with the 100 names, but this takes too long. If the ocr was just focusing on those 100 words and nothing else then it should be able to do all this in a split second. i.e. There is no point in guessing that a word might be "Jach" since "Jach" isn't a name in my database. The ocr should be able to infer that it is "Jack" since that is an actual name in the database.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible. Think of it this way: instead of having your OCR look for 'J' it could be looking for 'Jack' directly, sort of: as an individual *symbol*.

So when you train / calibrate your OCR, train it with images of whole words, similar to how you would - for an individual symbol.

(if this feature is not directly available in your OCR then first map images of whole words to a unique symbol and later transform that symbol into the final word string)